# Is it possible to find out the changes done to neo4j db over a time interval?

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to find out the updates / modifications / changes done to neo4j db over a time interval?

NEO4J DB will be polled at periodic intervals for finding the changes happened to it over that time period.

And then these changes have to be sync'd with other DBs.This is the real task.

Here changes include addition ,updation ,deletion of Nodes, Relationships,properties.

How do we track the changes that have been done in a particular timeframe. Not all nodes and relationships have timestamps set on it.

Comment: What about splitting up your question into paragraphs?

Answer (score 1):

Add a timestamp field to each of your nodes and relationships that inserts the timestamp() while they are created. Then write a cypher query to bring back all nodes and relationships within the given time range.

**EDIT**

There are two ways of implementing this synchronization.

*Option 1*

If you can use Spring Data Neo4j then you can use the lifecycle events as [explained here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/programming-model.html#d0e2498) to intercept the CUD operations and do the necessary synchronization either synchronously or asynchronously.

*Option 2*

If you can't use Spring, then you need to implement the interception code yourself. The best way I can think of is to **publish** all the CUD operations to a Topic and then write **subscribers** that can each synchronize to to each of the stores. In your case you have Neo4jSubscriber, DbOneSubscriber, Db2Subscriber etc.

Comment: Efficiently querying a timestamp field (by range) from Cypher is the hard part. :(

Comment: @WesFreeman Can't we store the timestamp as a long filed and use the range functions?

Comment: Yeah, that's true, if you use the legacy indexes. The new indexes don't have range lookups yet.

Comment: Thanks for ur response panega..but unfortunately it wont suits my requirement..i have just rephrased my rquirment above.

Comment: @sujanaummani check my updated answer. If I've answered your question then accept this as the answer.

Comment: Hi Panega,Yes i am accepting ur answers and thanks a million for dat.I happened to reject your answer previously as im new to this forum and dont know how this works..hope u understand

Comment: Here i wont be developing any application which vl interact with Neo4j and update it.My task is, i can only view the neo4j DB which will be getting updated by ohter system and i have to take the updates from this DB and synch vth the other siebel sys.any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is something called time tree where you use year month and day nodes to track changes and you can use this as well to get the history.
You also need to make sure you set the changing attributes / properties on the the relating object nodes when relating it to the day / month or year nodes

i hope this helps someone